# Bandwidth limits for Google Drive's publish site feature?

Tags: google-drive-api

Does anyone know what bandwidth limits are in place with the new website publishing feature for Google Drive?

https://developers.google.com/drive/publish-site

What if I serve music or other large files through these pages?

Answer (score 13):

Yes Google Drive website publishing feature does have quotas in place.

While we can't share the actual numbers, please note that websites hosted on Google Drive will be able to handle large loads which should meet the needs of most users publishing personal content.

However this is not intended for serving resources for very-high traffic websites (e.g. millions visits a day). Also there is currently no way to increase your quota. If you are looking for a professional solution for a high traffic website have a look at [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/).

When the quota is depleted a `403` HTTP error will be served for the remaining of the 24h period.

Answer (score 1):

According to this discussione looks like they don't apply a limit on the bandwidth: [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/drive/XFi7g-UcG2w/4nwWqWb2bfEJ)

The same should apply for the publishing feature. Looks like that they didn't put a limit to compete with services like Dropbox (which does), but obviously they should take measures in case of abuse.

Comment: This was before the web publishing feature. I've asked the thread if it still applies.

Comment: There are roughly the same limits for websites hosted on Google Drive and regular Google Drive files that are shared. The quota is not unlimited but the fact that people think it is is probably a good sign ;)