# Is it possible to use Google Drive as a host for my apps data? So app data can be online?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

Sorry if this ends up being long winded.

Just like a server where you can have data there and a user can have access to it with the right code. Can I put my text files on Google Drive, make them public and then allow my app access to them?

I've done this with a local webserver I created. `AsyncTask` interacts with a .php file on the server and the php file calls the data from a mySQL database. This of course works but since I can't afford to pay for a server is there an option for me to put my data in text files and host them on Google Drive? Then just use AsyncTask to call them? I get an error when trying it. I'm starting to think it's not possible.

Essentially, is there any way for me to use Google Drive as a server? Does anyone know of any other free sites that are reliable if I can't use it? I know my AyncTask code works because when I created a local server on an old laptop using XAMPP I was able to host a mySQL database and .php file that worked as mentioned above.

My app is currently offline only which I want to change so I don't have to send the user app updates via the Play Store every week.  Any advice?

Thanks for any help, I know this strictly isn't about code, or maybe it might be if Google Drive can be used.

Here is my app so you can understand the data I'm working with and how I want to show it: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.history.f1historyfree

Comment: You could look at [Parse](https://www.parse.com/plans).  They have a free plan which may work depending on how much data you want to pull down for each client and how many users you will have.

Comment: 1Gb is more than enough, I have 100 users at the moment so 1million requests seems more a lot, my users are rising day by day though. Hmm, so Google Drive is out of the question then? I'll look out for various sites if so. I've seen another app start a download of a text file when a users visits the page so that might be another option, host the files but request a download rather than allowing direct access. Don't think users will appreciate that though.

Comment: Well, Google Drive is usable, but this may not be quite what it is designed to do.  There are other options.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm going to try going with Google Drive first and see where that takes me before trying anything else.

Comment: Okay!  Let us know how it goes.

Comment: @i_am_jorf am feeling bad to say that parse is going to fully retire by january 28 of 2017 !

Comment: Indeed... if only I had the foresight to know that back in 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Use **[Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android)**, there is also an android specific example you can check  at https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-android-ui

Comment: Just to make sure, this allows me to store files on MY drive account and then all my users can have the data from it when they open my app? Just having a quick browse of the code suggests that this SDK is to allow each user access to their own account.

Comment: You can share files with other users too.

Comment: Cool, might take awhile before I mark this as the answer. Want to try to implement it first.

Comment: @RED_ Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: @biniam_Ethiopia Unfortunately not. I didn't need to explore it more than anything, sounds like it's possible judging by the answers. I would suggest doing what others have said myself though, paying a small amount for a web server. It shouldn't be more then £30 a year.

Answer (score 1):

If you go the Google Drive public file option then you may not even need the Drive SDK.

[Bandwidth limits for Google Drive's publish site feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675084/bandwidth-limits-for-google-drives-publish-site-feature)

http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2494827

If these are data files for your app, and it sounds like you only have a few users you could use Google App Engine to host the files and/or do any server side processing. Look at the free quota:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas

Anyone offering 'free' hosting, Google included, is expecting when you 'make it big' and hit the quota to upgrade.

For future proofing, setup your app so that you have a small online control file to redirect where the bulk of data lives without changing the app.

Comment: What do you mean by control file? Haven't come across such a thing.
Publishing my files is a good idea, making them public in a folder the way Drive suggest you do for a website. Those quotas aren't great but it's certainly ok-ish for now. I'll have to look into it.

Comment: If you want to switch hosting providers the app may either have a data url which you can redirect or a small (less than a kilobyte) control file which will have the url of where the data is located. If you use a control file you can setup additional features like upgrade messages. Again I'm just thinking of different ways to communicate with the app without having to upgrade it.

Comment: Yeah fair enough, sounds like a handy thing to have. My app has about 200 layouts, out of that less than 30 need to be updated weekly. I'm brainstorming and seeing if there's a way to overwrite those existing files when I need be, so 1) they are available offline and 2) they get updates OTA. 
Probably don't need as much bandwidth as I think I do, especially if those files become available offline, so users won't constantly be querying the server, it'll only query when there is an update for a file. Using the method you mentioned could be the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this tutorial 
https://developers.google.com/live/shows/192808437/
I have got my app running and this way is quite easy to use, as we can change the data directly on the spreadsheet.

+point : You can make the data as private, deploy by using your own email id, and make it accessible for 'anonymous'(i.e., for all, even for users who have not logged in their gmail account on their device). This way your database is still private and only accessible through the app.

M still struggling for importing 'images' from the spreadsheet to app :-/

Good luck with the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

> Yes you can

Google allows you to host your file for free.
upload your file > share that(public)> copy its id from its link.
**to download it directly you can use this link: *http://googledrive.com/host/[id]/***

i have a blog and i use google drive to host data .

see this : http://crackit9.blogspot.in/2016/05/beautiful-wallpapers-for-android.html